# angular 1 promise call http works, but not with fake data from json structure , promise.then not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-services

I have angularjs controller that return $http data fine, but I need to just return some hardcoded json structure data , but I'm getting  promise.then is not a function.

Seems it is not returning ,  like I need another return?

**Controller:**

```
 var promise = hearingFactory.getHearingSummary();

    promise.then(function (response) {
        vm.myData = response;
        console.log('getHearingSummary promise data', vm.myData);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    });
```

**Service**

```
var hearingFactory = function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getHearingSummary = function () {

        var url = "";
        url = baseUrl + "lib/questions";
        url = "test.json"

        //WORKS

        return $http.get(url).then(function (result) {
            console.log('service',result.data);
            return result.data;

        });

       // DOESN"T work  ( I comment out the above code)

        return {
            "flightData": [
                {
                    "MultiCarrier": false,
                    "Id": "O1"
                }
            ] 

        }

    }

    return factory;

};
```

1. nothing is wrong with my controller code, nor the overall service code
2. seems to be that double return promise in the .then for $http "works"
3. perhaps i need a true "promise" for the json structure of data, if so , how would i write that?

Answer (score 1):

The first one "works" because `.then()` produces a promise. Your second `return` statement is returning a plain object, which isn't a promise. You're trying to call `.then` on something that isn't a promise.

So return a promise:

```
return $q.when({
    "flightData": [
        {
            "MultiCarrier": false,
            "Id": "O1"
        }
    ] 
});
```

Comment: @ScottLeary It is if you're using a new enough version of AngularJS, but if not, you can use `$q.when()`.

Comment: @TomStickel No, `$q` is part of AngularJS.

Comment: @TomStickel `q-` is something else. And there's also [a promise library named `Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). The `$q` in AngularJS' is named after the latter but is not directly related to either.